# Index and matching column under year and month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I am using an excel formula to index and match the correct number amount for the correct item number. The output is a table and I am having trouble finding the number amount for item numbers in 2019.

I attached a pic of the example workbook and highlighted what I cannot find. I think it is just a matter of adding another MATCH somewhere in the excel formula but I am not too sure where.

Any help is appreciated and please let me know if you need any more information. I tried to make the workbook as self explanatory as possible.

**The formula for the first cell in the table:**

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$6:$H$20,MATCH($N6,$B$6:$B$20,0),MATCH(O$5,$C$5:$I$5,0)),"0")`

The workbook:
[Please let me know of any questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw6DG.png)

Comment: try creating a key for the month-year pair so that it becomes unique and use that in the second match parameter

Comment: Ok, what would be an example key?

Comment: I recently answered a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345010/excel-match-offset-index-for-multiple-columns/52347308#52347308

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I will use it as a resource as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above you can have a unique key to use in the offset formula so that the correct numbers populate

You could create month-year unique key to be used as the lookup array inside the match function
- say, you could have the formula `=CONCATENATE(C5, "-", C4)` starting at `C3`
- you could then modify your formula in cell `O6` as `=IFERROR(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($N6,$B$6:$B$20,0),MATCH(CONCATENATE(O5,"-",O4),$C$3:$J$3,0)),"0")`
- this is assuming you have the month-year key in the cells C3-J3

Comment: Ok I see, that's helpful. Other resources were concatenating as well and I was trying to avoid that but that is completely fine. Thanks for the suggestion! When my workbook is complete I can come back here with my final formula

Comment: Just to update the thread as I said I would, my final formula in cell V6 is `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$6:$J$20,MATCH($N6,$B$6:$B$20,0),MATCH(V$5&$R$4,$C$3:$J$3,0)),"0")` assuming row 3 is `=i5&i4`